# How to convert GrayScale image to byte array?

Tags: c#, image, arrays

I have grayscale image and i want to see its byte[] is there anyway to do this ?

Here i get grayscaleimage ;

```
 private void OnImage(NGrayscaleImage nImage)
 {
 }
```

And i want to send it to this function ;

```
 private void SendBiometricInfo(byte[] imageBuffer, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
 {
 }
```

Is there anyway to do this ? If so could you help me to handle this issue ?

**Here is what i tried ...**

```
private void OnImage(NGrayscaleImage nImage)
{
    OnImageByte(ImageToByte(nImage), nImage.Width, nImage.Height);               
    //However here it says there is an invalid arguments.
}


public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}

void OnImageByte(byte[] imgBuffer, int width, int height)
{
}
```

Comment: What is `NGrayscaleImage`? And what is wrong with what you have currently tried?

Comment: What do you want to see? its representation as a GIF? PNG? BMP?

Comment: I can use nImage.Save() function and i can save it as jpg.

Comment: @musefan i am using .dll so it is an image format.

Comment: @goGud: Not one that we know anything about... how do you expect us to help you when you are using an unknown class? You need to provide more information about this class

Answer (score 0):

If you can save your image as JPG, is presumible that your `NGrayscaleImage` inherits from [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you could try to save it into a memory stream

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
       image.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
       return ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.